# What is the password for monero.hashvault.pro pool?

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, gpu-mining, pool-mining

Hello this is probably a stupid question but. 
I set up some xmrig miners with this config:

```
{
"pools": [
{
"url": "pool.monero.hashvault.pro:5555",
"user" :"xxxxxxmygui-wallet-address",
"pass" : "worker_id",
"keepalive" : "true",
"nicehash" : "false"
}
]
}
```

I wanted to log in to check statistics on *monero.hashvault.pro*.

I put my Monero GUI wallet address as login but for the password I have no clue what to enter, I tried "worker_id" but that wasn't correct.

From the instructions:

```
Password (email field from "pool_password")
```

What am supposed to enter?

Did I forget to add this setting to my config.json?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The password field is utilized to better identify your worker, but I assume you are only using your CPU, so it's fine to leave it as "x".

On hashvault.pro exchange the only thing required to track your current impending balance is your wallet address. Of course, the same address you put in your configuration.

https://monero.hashvault.pro/en/#!/dashboard

Go to the dashboard, and find "track live stats" and enter your wallet address.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to log in as to get the stats you just add your wallet address to the dashboard or visit this URL replacing "wallet-address" with your own

https://monero.hashvault.pro/en/dashboard/wallet-address

When you log in you can adjust payment thresholds or set email notifications of down rigs. If this is of interest you can follow our guide: https://hashvault.pro/help/en/interface-help/how-to-login

You can also get down notifications from our Android monitoring app, so you only really need to login if you need to adjust the payment threshold or you do want email notifications.